# ViewController is appearing 2-5 times on Push, login screen using Firebase (video)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, segue, firebase-authentication

[YOUTUBE VIDEO OF PROBLEM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLE76pgY3Ng&feature=youtu.be)

RootViewController - (Home Screen) - This is the very first screen, Firebase then detects if a user is already logged in on startup or they just signed up and then it logs them in.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

            FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in

            if user != nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I'm dismissing controllers and the same action that gets triggered when signing out a user to return to the home screen:

```
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you see the video link, that's what's happening, and I don't know why or what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener()` is getting called multiple times when you are logging in with a user and its the reason why the view is getting pushed multiple times.

Would there be a chance to change your code to this?

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
  // User is signed in.
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: nil)
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That works if the app is starting app and a user was logged in, but how do I get (1) the login screen with username and password to go the home controller and (2) when the user signs up to go same screen? How do I do that by using segues from different view controllers to a single one.

Comment: I took your advice and just presented everything modally, only used segues to pass data, but just created a lazy var global class. Thanks!